# Where is htaccess located in Drupal 7?

Tags: installation

I'm looking for the .htaccess file that should be in the default installation of Drupal 7.

Normally it is supposed to be there. Does anyone know where it is located?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file's called `.htaccess` and it's in the root of the Drupal installation. A lot of operating systems hide files that start with a `.`, so that might be way you can't find it.

If it's simply missing, just download a fresh copy of Drupal and copy the default `.htaccess` file from there.

Comment: if you are using nix system, one can do a "ls -a" to see the .htacess file